# Regex for getting string in outer curly braces containing multiple inner curly braces

Tags: javascript, regex, curly-braces

i need to find the regex to give me a string in curly braces, where the string also contains curly braces. This is the string is like

```
input{
    stdin {
     type => "stdin-type"
       }
    file {
     type => "file"
      }
}

output {
      stdout { }
}
```

What i want is for example just the input part. My latest try was:

```
input{([\s\S]*)\n}
```

This works, when there is only one inner pair of curly braces and a newline before the last curly brace, but that might not always be the case. And there may be even more inner elements with curly braces. So i need something more flexible. Something with an open counter or alike.

And i need it for javascript.

Perhaps it is not makeable with regex??

Ideas welcome.

tmoe

Comment: You can try your regex online at : https://regex101.com/#javascript

Comment: Matching Nested braces isn't possible for all the cases in JS. For your input try: [`/input{([^]*?)\n}/`](https://regex101.com/r/nN2eB2/1)

Comment: Would you show us what the result should be for the given string ? And for another, if it does not bother you.

Comment: This looks like a classic XY problem. You should be parsing JSON here, not using regex on a string.

Comment: Could you precise exactly the output that you want pls ?

Comment: Result should be     `stdin {
     type => "stdin-type"
       }
    file {
     type => "file"
      }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having logic in regex to match nested patterns might bring you into a nightmare and regex may not be the right tool for this.

Basing on your regex, I can come up with some changes and using this one:

```
input{([\s\S]*?)^}
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/pU3kB5/3)**

It will use the start line with `}` as the end delimiter which could solve your specific problem, however regex may not be the best answer for your problem.